# FirstName, LastName in SQL, too complex?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This SQL seems complex, is there an easier way to get FirstName, LastName when one or both of the fields can be NULL?

```
SELECT COALESCE(LastName,'')+
       CASE WHEN LastName+FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' END+
       COALESCE(FirstName,'') AS Name
FROM Person
```

Comment: If you are often going to need names displayed like this, It might be worth it to create a persistent calculated field.

Comment: @HLGEM - Interesting, maybe an answer would make clear your suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, 
                LastName, FirstName) Name
FROM Person
```

if `firstname` or `lastname` is null the entire first expression (with the `,`), becomes null, forcing the coalesce to examine, second, the `lastname` alone, and then if `lastname` is null, finally, the `firstname` alone.

Comment: Actually, you forgot one:

COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName, 'This poor sucker has no name')

Just kidding, of course.

Comment: Would this work since you are putting a comma in the coalesce? I might have just learned something new if it does work, but I would think that there would never be a chance for this to be NULL.

Comment: When you concatenate a string to a null string in TSQL you get null.  The string constant goes to null in the first argument if either is null.

Comment: a general one: set @userName = RTRIM(ISNULL(@firstname + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@middleName + ', ', '') + ISNULL(@surname, ''))

Comment: @isuruceanu - This does not work.  If middleName and surname are null you get a hanging comma -- what we are trying to avoid.

Comment: @isuruceanu, `middleName`?? Where do you see that?  and, as described above by others, if `firstname` or `lastname` is null the entire first expression is null, forcing the coalesce to examine, second, the `lastname` alone, and then if `lastname` is null, finally, the `firstname` alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can precalculate this in a table by using a peristed calculated column if you will be using this form of the name often. The column could even be indexed if you needed it to be.

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD [person_name_last_first]  AS COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, 
                LastName, FirstName) PERSISTED
```

The biggest advantage is that you never have to write this piece of code again, names will be consistently displayed and that you only use the databases time to perform this action when the first and last names are added or changed.

Comment: +1, nb, this is available in all platforms with slightly different syntax

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this is complex at all...
On MSSQL you can do something like

```
SELECT Isnull(LastName,'') + ', ' + Isnull(FirstName,'')
FROM Person
```

Comment: This would return a comma if the names are null which I think is poor. I won't downvote it, but won't upvote it either. :)

Comment: This does not work... you get results like "Frist, " and ", Last"

Comment: Sorry, but in the question the user do not specify it.

Comment: @mRt, really?  You would output hanging commas in your code because someone did not specify it?

Comment: I don't know. I just post an example where I use the Isnull().

Comment: It's clear from the original post that the developer was interesting covering cases where one of the values might be null.