# NULL values turn everything into NULL during concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

The DBMS I'm working with is MySQL.

Here's the table:

```
                    AUTHOR
author_id | first_name | last_name | patronymic
-----------------------------------------------
     1    | John       | Bush      | NULL
     2    | Sergey     | Burov     | Romanovich
     3    | NULL       | Filin     | NULL
```

If I issue this query:

```
SELECT author_id,
       CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name,  ' ', patronymic) AS full_name
FROM   author;
```

The output looks like this:

```
author_id | full_name
-----------------------------------
     1    | NULL
     2    | Sergey Burov Romanovich
     3    | NULL
```

So, as you can see from the example, if a field has a NULL value, then during the concatenation process the whole thing gets set to NULL. Please, explain, how to make MySQL convert NULL values to a string of length 0 or simply make it so that it does not concatenate NULL values at all?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please don’t tell me you’re _suprised_ by this happening – because the documentation explicitly mentions it! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: I'm kind of new to the world of database programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) that concatenates strings using a separator, and skipping null values:

```
SELECT author_id,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name,  patronymic) AS full_name
FROM   author;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf5c9/1).

Answer (score 0):

This is way to answer your question directly:

```
SELECT author_id,
       CONCAT(ISNULL(first_name,''), ' ', 
              ISNULL(last_name,''),  ' ',
              ISNULL(patronymic,'')) AS full_name
FROM author;
```

or even this (solves double space issues with null middle name):

```
SELECT author_id,
       CONCAT(ISNULL(CONCAT(first_name,' '),''), 
              ISNULL(CONCAT(last_name,' '),''),
              ISNULL(patronymic,'')) AS full_name
FROM author;
```

But this will answer the real question -- best solution to do nice formatting in this or slightly more complicated situations:

[FirstName, LastName in SQL, too complex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851037/firstname-lastname-in-sql-too-complex)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `COALESCE` on all the columns to guarantee they never return null (by either returning the value, or an empty string)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author_id,
   CONCAT(ifnull(first_name,''), ' ', ifnull(last_name,''),  ' ', ifnull(patronymic,'')) AS full_name FROM   author;
```